# Title does not appear in TabBarItem, but the image does

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, tabbarcontroller

I've added a tab bar controller and am trying to add a title and image to the item, but only the image shows. The title is nowhere to be seen. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
_tabbarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
_showsController = [[showsController alloc] init];
_showsController.title = @"Test1";
_showsController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Glass.png"];
[_tabbarController setViewControllers: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: _showsController, nil]];
```

UPDATE:
After searching stackoverflow for a while, I finally found the solution by adding the following code:
*self.view = _tabbarController.view;*

I apologize for not giving more information (that this was not the rootViewController but added as a subview instead), and thank you for your help.

Comment: Is your tabBarController the root ViewController? (it should be)

Comment: But then why is the image for that barItem working?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the title on the `UITabBarItem` object.

```
_showsController.tabBarItem.title = _showsController.title;
```

Personally, I prefer to let the UIViewController subclass handle its own titles when possible. This makes your code more self-contained and doesn't always force the UIViewController's creator to initialize it properly.

For example, in your UIViewController subclass:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]))
    {
        UITabBarItem *item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test1"
                                                           image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Glass.png"]
                                                             tag:1];
        [self setTabBarItem:item];
        [item release];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Tried that one, but did not work as expected. I feel like I'm missing something essential.

Comment: @liquidpenguins I just edited my answer with the way I usually setup UITabBars.

Comment: Thanks, that does clean up the code. Unfortunately, my stubborn tab controller still refuses to show the title.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `UITabBarItem` title:

```
 _showsController.tabBarItem.title = @"Test1";
```

Or set them both in one go:

```
_showsController.title = _showsController.tabBarItem.title = @"Test1";
```

Comment: It should work? unless you wrap the `_showsController` in a `UINavigationController` then you need to set the `<UINavigationController>.tabBarItem.title`.

Comment: No, it's not in a navController.